# How to automate a native OS file upload window in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, file-upload, selenium

I am using **selenium and python** to automate a **file upload application** for the past many hours but nothing helpful! The HTML DOM structure for this file upload is an **input tag with its type attribute value = 'file'**. So I can make use of the send_keys. The problem is I am not supposed to use send_keys() (as per the question).

Can anyone suggest me alternative ways to upload the file? I do get solutions for windows but not for Linux(Ubuntu)
I know there are applications/tools to automate GUI components like **AutoIt** but there is nothing for Linux close to AutoIt.

I have done my homework to find a solution. Only after not finding anything useful, I am asking this question, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I belive that  `gtk.gtk.Display` would do the job.

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkdisplay.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but would you please tell me how to use it? I mean a small example so that I can try your solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I  cannot.  I don't actually know Python.  In Java I would use the Robots class, and found the most similar class I could in Python.  Other SO questions may help you.